# Can dupe hammer power be abused to obtain the I'm Batman hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

The scenario can be quite simple:

1. Find a question that was closed as duplicate (that I did not participate in closing) having a tag for which I have a gold badge.
2. Make some edit to that question.
3. Use my binding vote to reopen that question.

This seems to fit the hat description perfectly - `edit a closed question (that you did not participate in closing) that gets reopened after your edit`.

Will it work? If it works, it might encourage some bad behavior of reopening duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

I almost tried it yesterday, with a question that was a real duplicate, but I felt bad about reopening that question, so I didn't.

I ended up getting the I'm a Batman hat doing something similar, but not quite. I found a question in the Reopen Votes queue that was closed as duplicate. It was in the Java tag, in which I have a gold badge. It appeared that the OP made a legit edit and a legit claim that it wasn't an actual duplicate. I chose to edit and reopen, making some minor edits that improved the question slightly.

I did get the hat for that question, but my vote was one of [5 votes to re-open that question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34272159/revisions), so perhaps having the dupe hammer power didn't have any effect here. Still, it looks like this would have worked even if my vote was a binding vote.

**It would be nice to get a confirmation regarding whether it can be done when the binding vote is not one of 5 votes to reopen**. I can't test it on other sites, since I only have gold tag badges on SO.